# Why is the Icon in my title bar is different from times to times (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm drawing an icon in another class that I call: 
`Image logo = new LogoRosemont().logo;`

And then setting it to my JFrame :`setIconImage(logo);`

But the Icon is sometimes perfect, other times partial and often black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I corrected the problem by placing the `setIconImage(logo);` at the end of my Constructor. The problem was that it was often not drawn completely before getting it.
It depended upon how the processing time was shared between the two tasks : JFrame drawing and Logo drawing.

Hope it helps others. ^^